# Design for a C++ class to undo modifications to another class member

Tags: c++, design-patterns, undo

I have a composition of objects with a cumbersome design.
Classes X and Y are a schematic representation of this design, where Y is a component of X.

```
class Y {
public:
    std::string _name;
    Y(std::string name) : _name(name) {}
};

class X {
    Y _y;
public:
    X(std::string name) : _y(name) {}
    Y getY() { return _y; }
    Y* getYPtr() { return &_y; }
};
```

Note that `std::string _name` in `Y` is public.

What I want to do is to access `Y::_name` through an instance of `X`, to write new values for it, and to have the possibility to undo a write operation easily in other portions of the program.

My attempt is as follows: I use an `Undo` object which contains three information:

- The pointer to the string on which the undo takes effect
- The string containing the oldname
- The string containing the new name

.

```
class Undo {
    std::string _oldName;
    std::string _newName;
    std::string *_internalName;
public:
    Undo(std::string *name) : _internalName(name) {}
    void setOldName(std::string oldName) {
        _oldName = oldName;
    }
    void setNewName(std::string newName) { 
        _newName = newName;
    }
    void undoToOldName() {
        *_internalName = _oldName;
    }
};
```

If I want to undo a write operation, I only need to invoke the `undoToOldName()` method on the `Undo` object.

Example:

```
X x("firstName");

Y *y = x.getYPtr();

// Prepare the undo object
Undo undo(&(y->_name));
undo.setOldName(y->_name);
undo.setNewName("secondName");

// Set new name
y->_name = "secondName";

// Output: secondName
std::cout << x.getY()._name << std::endl;

// Undo
undo.undoToOldName();

// Output: firstName
std::cout << x.getY()._name << std::endl;
```

The thing I don't like with this design is the need for the `Y *` getter.

As a constraint, I cannot change the design of the composition.

Could you please suggest alternative designs for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is a `X::setY()` method permitted? If so, it would allow removal of `getYPtr()` and implementation of a `X::rollbackY()` method.

Comment: Maybe make your Undo class a friend of Y, so it can set `_y._name`?  If you want Undo to remember which X or Y to work on, it can take a reference in the constructor and - using the initialiser list - record it for later use.  Avoid pointers.  Frankly, it's all a bit of a mess though... :-(

Comment: @hmjd thanks for comment. No, that wouldn't be possible because one `X` has many objects similar to `Y`. Only one of them is valid and this is determined by an Enumerate. Once I discover which `Y` to edit, I don't want to go through the Enumerates anymore. Further, one `Y` has many `_y`s, and not all of them are eligible for an undo. I admit the design is ugly, but that's the library I have :).

Comment: @TonyDelroy thanks for the suggestion, but I think this wouldn't work because of the many `y_`s inside Y. It's my fault to have omitted this detail in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protecting invariance on revisions with object modifiers is exceptionally tricky.  If you need to rollback multiple fields at once and one fails, what do you do?  Your revision control could actually influence how the normal operation of the object works as well.

A simple way to version objects is to keep around all the versions of the objects.  When you need to rollback, you just replace it with a copy of the old version.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments: the `Undo` object shouldn't need a `setOldName` method. It can figure it out, since it has the string pointer. Secondly, it doesn't need `setNewName` either; it just needs a method to tell it *when* the new value is set. (Assuming you need it at all, which I doubt)

A nice setup is to have `getYPtr()` return an `undo_ptr<Y>`. This is a thin shim, which knows about the associated `Undo` object. When `undo_ptr<Y>::~undo_ptr` is called, i.e. when the client is done, the associated `Undo::newNameSet` method is called. As noted above, this just extracts the new value via the provided pointer.

Example:

```
X x("firstName");
{  
  Undo undo(x, &X::name); // Slightly cleaner interface. Saves "firstName".
  Y* y = x.getYPtr();
  y->_name = "secondName";
  // Output: secondName
  std::cout << x.getY()._name << std::endl;
  // Undo (calls Undo::operator(), the convention for functors).
  undo();
  // Output: firstName
  std::cout << x.getY()._name << std::endl;
}
```

As you see, there's no need in this case to capture the new name, so you don't need the framework of a `undo_ptr<Y>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why a new class? You can extend class `X` with `beginTransaction`, `commitTransaction` and `rollbackTransaction` methods, as well as an `update` method that will optionally assert if it is called outside of transaction.